# postgresql Get weeks of the month from date

Tags: postgresql

I have this postgresql query

```
SELECT pick.min_date, extract('week' from pick.min_date) as week FROM account_invoice inv 
left join stock_picking pick on inv.origin=pick.name 
WHERE inv.number ='INV/2022/17359'
```

and the results are

```
min_date            | week
2022-08-11 02:01:00 | 32
```

What I need for the week column is number 2 because the date (11) is in the 2nd weeks of august. Any help will be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the week number of the target date from the week number of the first day of the month of the target date and add one. Here is your query with this modification.

```sql
SELECT pick.min_date, 
  extract('week' from pick.min_date) - 
  extract('week' from date_trunc('month', pick.min_date)) + 1 as week 
FROM account_invoice inv 
left join stock_picking pick on inv.origin=pick.name 
WHERE inv.number ='INV/2022/17359';
```

Demo

```sql
SELECT  
  extract('week' from '2022-08-11'::date) - 
  extract('week' from date_trunc('month', '2022-08-11'::date)) + 1;

-- yields 2
```

Comment: It works. i choose this one. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use date part for these extractions

```
select 
  ((date_part('day', dt::date)::integer - 1) / 7) +1 as currentweekofthemonth, 
date_part('week', dt::date) AS weekoftheyear,
date_part('month', dt::date)  AS mon,
 date_part('year', dt::date)  AS yr from 
  
  
  (select '2022-08-11 02:01:00' as dt) as drt ;
```

OUTPUT :

```
currentweekofthemonth   weekoftheyear   mon     yr
2   32  8   2022
```